# Is there a function to compare two DataFrames and output the different elements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare two different DataFrames to check the new_df symbol does it exists in old_df, if it doesnt exist in the old_df, I want to output to a list.

Code looks like this:

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'H']})
```

I want the output like this:

```
['F','H']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isin()` as a mask

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'H']})

new_df[~np.isin(new_df.values,old_df.values)].values
```

### output

```
array([['F'],
       ['H']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
>>> set(new_df.symbol.unique()) - set(old_df.symbol.unique())
{'F', 'H'}
```

Using the python built-in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).